# Can't subscribe to CheckinEvent

Tags: wcf, tfs

I am trying to subscribe to CheckinEvent, for some reason my Notify method isn't called.
This is my contract -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
namespace TFSubscriber
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
    public interface IRollupService
    {

        [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
        void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml);

    }
}
```

My implementation is pretty simple, empty method. I put a breakpoint in my Notify method and it's not called.

This how I subscribe to CheckinEvent -

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server2010\Tools>bissubscribe.exe /eventType CheckInEvent /address http://localhost:4556/Rollupservice.svc /collection http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

I have a solution that I added to source control already, and I am checkin' some files and the breakpoint isn't getting hit.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your subscription works?  For example try logging some information regarding input parameter eventXML. Because, you need to be sure about if your subscription works or not. If so, you can run your SVC project and attach a debugger on it. That is how debugger supposed to hit your breakpoint.